# For loops for running a function on columns

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to run a test for each species of ant that I have (columns 9-13) that compares values in the following columns: `Attack_count`, `Attack_percent`, `Survival_count`, and
`Survival_percent`. I want to make this comparison when individual ant species are `ants>0` to when they are  `ant==0`.

This is what I have tried, and it returns `pvalue=NA` multiple times. This is my first attempt at writing a `for` loop and I do not know how to incorporate `i`.

I added in the bootstrap code. I am not exactly sure how making a reproducible example goes but I wrote one in

```
bootstrap_ttest <- function(data1,data2,resamples){

    delta_real <- mean(data1) - mean(data2) ##real diff btwn means
    pooled_data <- c(data1, data2)

    null_differences <-c()
    for(x in 1:1000){

        data1_null <- sample(pooled_data,size=length(data1), replace=T)
        data2_null <- sample(pooled_data,size=length(data2), replace=T)

        delta_null <- mean(data1_null) - mean(data2_null)
        null_differences <- c(null_differences, delta_null )

    }## end of resampling loop 

    pvalue <- sum(abs(null_differences) > abs(delta_real))/length(null_differences)
    cat("pvalue:", pvalue)
    assign("pvalue", pvalue,.GlobalEnv) 
    assign("null_dist", null_differences,.GlobalEnv )
    assign("delta_obs", delta_real,.GlobalEnv )

}
ac_pvals = vector(length = ncol(ants))
ap_pvals = vector(length = ncol(ants))
sc_pvals = vector(length = ncol(ants))
sp_pvals = vector(length = ncol(ants))

for(i in 1:ncol(ants)){

  ants = data.frame(mainbroca[,9:13])

test1 = bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Attack_count[ants == 0], 
                data2=mainbroca$Attack_count[ants>0], resamples=1000)
test2 = bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Attack_percent[ants == 0], 
                data2=mainbroca$Attack_percent[ants>0], resamples=1000)
test3 = bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Survival_count[ants == 0], 
                data2=mainbroca$Survival_count[ants>0], resamples=1000)
test4 = bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Survival_percent[ants == 0], 
                data2=mainbroca$Survival_percent[ants>0], resamples=1000)

ac_pvals[1] = c(test1)
ap_pvals[1] = c(test2)
sc_pvals[1] = c(test3)
sp_pvals[1] = c(test4)

}

#reproducible

fakerow1 <- c(1,2,3,4,100,80,60,40,20)
fakerow2 <- c(1,2,3,4,100,80,60,40,20)
fakedata = rbind(fakerow1,fakerow2)
colnames(fakedata) = c('ac','ap','sc','sp','ant1','ant2','ant3','ant4','ant5')
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you used? Thanks.

Comment: @Jannice Newson, from which packages the function `bootstrap_ttest` is coming from ? I'm not able to find it online. Also, instead of attached images, can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data, it will facilitate copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I update my answer too accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to do what I think you want. You were looping over the columns and needed to filter the ants dataset by column and then save the results to your vectors without overwriting.

```
ants = data.frame(mainbroca[,9:13])

ac_pvals = vector()
ap_pvals = vector()
sc_pvals = vector()
sp_pvals = vector()

for(i in 1:ncol(ants)){

bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Attack_count[ants[,i] == 0], 
                data2=longbroca$Attack_count[ants[,i]>0], resamples=1000)
ac_pvals = c(ac_pvals, pvalue)
bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Attack_percent[ants[,i] == 0], 
                data2=longbroca$Attack_percent[ants[,i]>0], resamples=1000)
ap_pvals = c(ap_pvals, pvalue)
bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Survival_count[ants[,i] == 0], 
                data2=longbroca$Survival_count[ants[,i]>0], resamples=1000)
sc_pvals = c(sc_pvals, pvalue)
bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Survival_percent[ants[,i] == 0], 
                data2=longbroca$Survival_percent[ants[,i]>0], resamples=1000)
sp_pvals = c(sp_pvals, pvalue)
}
```

Comment: This worked, but the vectors to save pvalues do not have the pvalues in them. The pvalues print out after running the loop, but when I view the vectors, there are different numbers within them

Comment: I must admit I assumed that bootstrap_ttest output the p-value. I have updated my code to fit your function. Your fake data looks quite different from what your code implied. There are a different number of columns and different variable names.  You will also probably need more rows to bootstrap. Also, your bootstrap code seems to be hardcoded to run 1000 time rather than use resamples.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating your question and providing informations about your `bootstrap_ttest` function.

1) There is a little mistake on your `function`. the `resample` variable is not used, I think you should replace `for(x in 1:1000)` by `for(x in 1:resample)`.

2) Here, a possible way to simplify your code (maybe not the best one) by defining two `for` loop. The first one will loop across columns of `ants` and the second will repeat the `bootstrap_ttest` function to each column selected. Then, you can bind `pvalues` and `delta_obs` in two dataframes that you can ultimately bind.

Here is the code to define variables to loop:

```r
# Defining columns to be tested 
colonne = c("Attack_counts","Attack_percent","Survival_count","Survival_percent")
# Defining ants dataframe
ants = mainbroca[,c(9:13)]
```

And here is the double loop:

```r
result_pval = NULL
result_t_boot = NULL

for(j in 1:ncol(ants))
{
  P.val =NULL
  t_bootstrap = NULL
  for(i in 1:length(colonne))
  {
    t <- bootstrap_ttest(data1 = mainbroca[ants[,j]==0,colonne[i]]), data2 = mainbroca[ants[,j]>0,colonne[i]], resamples = 1000]
    P.val = c(P.val,pvalue)
    t_bootstrap = c(t_bootstrap,t)
  }
  result_pval = cbind(result_pval,P.val)
  result_t_boot = cbind(result_t_boot,t_bootstrap)
}
```

And to get the final dataframe:

```r
colnames(result_pval) = paste0(colnames(ants),"_pval")
colnames(result_t_boot) = paste0(colnames(ants),"_DeltaObs")
Final_df = cbind(result_pval,result_t_boot)
rownames(Final_df) = colonne
```

At the end, you should get a dataframe of 8 columns and 4 rows. First 4 columns, you will get `pvalue` from your `bootstrap_ttest` function for each `ants` column and the last 4 column will contain `delta_obs` calculated for each `ants` column. Rows will be each columns tested (Attacks, Survival,...)

Does it looks what you are looking for ?

Comment: This returns ```argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA```

Comment: Do you have NA in your data.frame ? Can you provide the output of `str(mainbroca)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this.

```
ants = data.frame(mainbroca[,9:13])
cols_table = c('Attack_count', 'Attack_percent','Survival_count', 'Survival_percent')

ac_pvals = NULL
ap_pvals = NULL
sc_pvals = NULL
sp_pvals = NULL

#attack count
for(i in 1:ncol(ants)){

bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Attack_count[ants[,i] == 0], 
                data2=mainbroca$Attack_count[ants[,i]>0], resamples=1000)
  ac_pvals = c(ac_pvals, pvalue)
}

#attack percent
for(i in 1:ncol(ants)){
bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Attack_percent[ants[,i] == 0], 
                data2=mainbroca$Attack_percent[ants[,i]>0], resamples=1000)
   ap_pvals = c(ap_pvals, pvalue)
}

#survival count
for(i in 1:ncol(ants)){
bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Survival_count[ants[,i] == 0], 
                data2=mainbroca$Survival_count[ants[,i]>0], resamples=1000)
   sc_pvals = c(sc_pvals, pvalue)
}

#survival percent
for(i in 1:ncol(ants)){
bootstrap_ttest(data1=mainbroca$Survival_percent[ants[,i] == 0], 
                data2=mainbroca$Survival_percent[ants[,i]>0], resamples=1000)
  sp_pvals = c(sp_pvals, pvalue)
}

ttest1 = print(ac_pvals)
ttest2 = print(ap_pvals)
ttest3 = print(sc_pvals)
ttest4 = print(sp_pvals)

ptable = cbind(ac_pvals, ap_pvals,sc_pvals,sp_pvals)
rownames(ptable) = c("Was", "Pmor", "Monom", "Brachy", "Sinv")
```